# self._cursor.next() exception in py.test with mongomock

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pymongo, mongoengine

I have encountered a problem when running py.test for my Django rest framework API using mongodb backend, while the view works in real action.

If I start the server, the API works as expected. Only when running the test, it fails for `self._cursor` being a list instead of an iterator.

I wonder if there is anything to do with pymongo's mongomock and Django rest framework pagination.

Here are the setups:

## settings_test.py

```
# override the mongodb with mocks for pytest
mongoengine.register_connection(
    'default',
    name='testing',
    host='mongomock://localhost',
    # let datetime in pymongo/mongoengine with timezone information
    tz_aware=True)

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
```

## View under testing

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.generics import ListAPIView
class ListPropertyApi(ListAPIView):
    queryset = PropertyObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer
```

## pytest

```
class TestListPropertyApi:
    def test_lonlat_query(self, rf):
        request = rf.get(
            u'/property/list/')
        view = views.ListPropertyApi.as_view()
        response = view(request)
```

## error message

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py:58: in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py:68: in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py:466: in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py:463: in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
share/cache.py:96: in get
    return decorated_get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
lib/rest_framework_mongoengine/generics.py:77: in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py:42: in list
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/generics.py:172: in paginate_queryset
    return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py:448: in paginate_queryset
    results = list(queryset[offset:offset + self.page_size + 1])
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py:80: in _iter_results
    self._populate_cache()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py:92: in _populate_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self.next())
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = .. queryset mid-iteration ..

    def next(self):
        """Wrap the result in a :class:`~mongoengine.Document` object.
            """
        if self._limit == 0 or self._none:
            raise StopIteration

>       raw_doc = self._cursor.next()
E       AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py:1407: AttributeError
```

## Environment

```
mongoengine==0.10.6
mongomock==3.3.0
pymongo==3.2.2
djangorestframework==3.3.3
pytest-django==2.9.1
Django==1.9.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it ended up easy to fix by following this issue https://github.com/vmalloc/mongomock/issues/130

Comment: It looks like the only solution is clone and modify the mongomock. Just wondering why this fix never get into the release? I'm hoping not to maintain my own branch whenever possible. (note I have upgraded to 3.4 but it is still not fixed)